# React JS how do I transform this array of objects with dates and numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a React component which is pulling JSON data from a get call and I need to reformat it (I'm still a newbie when it comes to array manipulation). Here is the initial returned JSON:

```
{
"metrics": {
    "2018-12-26 18:00:00": {
        "20": 451,
        "30": 48
    },
    "2018-12-26 19:00:00": {
        "20": 165
    },
    "2018-12-27 00:00:00": {
        "20": 177,
        "30": 8
    },
    "2018-12-27 01:00:00": {
        "20": 220
    },
    "2018-12-27 02:00:00": {
        "20": 220
    },
    "2018-12-27 03:00:00": {
        "20": 177,
        "30": 8
    },
    "2018-12-27 04:00:00": {
        "20": 220
    },
    "2018-12-28 00:00:00": {
        "20": 93
    },
    "2018-12-28 01:00:00": {
        "20": 76
    },
    "2018-12-28 02:00:00": {
        "20": 76
    },
    "2018-12-28 03:00:00": {
        "20": 57
    },
    "2018-12-28 04:00:00": {
        "20": 76
    },
    "2018-12-28 15:00:00": {
        "20": 130,
        "30": 10
    }
}
}
```

What I need to is separate this into the individual dates and add the "20" and "30" numbers together so that I would end up with something like this for each date:

```
"2018-12-26": { 
     "20": total number here,
     "30": total number here
 }
```

I know this will involve Object.keys and perhaps destructing but I am getting nowhere fast. Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: I believe you're right, Object.keys will be involved. But you'll need to post what code you have, showing what you've tried and where the code is failing.

Comment: Yes, like @Toby says, post the relevant react code

Comment: Okay will do thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

So here the idea is first will create a `empty object` to store our `final output`. Now we will loop through all the keys of the given object and check if that key is already in `output object` or not if it's their we add the respective `key's value` to output object if not than we create a new property in `output object`.

```js
let data = { "metrics": { "2018-12-26 18:00:00": {"20": 451, "30": 48 },"2018-12-26 19:00:00": { "20": 165 },   "2018-12-27 00:00:00": { "20": 177, "30": 8 },  "2018-12-27 01:00:00": {  "20": 220 }, "2018-12-27 02:00:00": { "20": 220 }, "2018-12-27 03:00:00": {       "20": 177,  "30": 8   }, "2018-12-27 04:00:00": {       "20": 220  }, "2018-12-28 00:00:00": {  "20": 93  },   "2018-12-28 01:00:00": { "20": 76 },"2018-12-28 02:00:00": { "20": 76 }, "2018-12-28 03:00:00": {      "20": 57  }, "2018-12-28 04:00:00": { "20": 76 },   "2018-12-28 15:00:00": { "20": 130, "30": 10 }}}

let op = {}

for(let key in data['metrics']){
  let temp= new Date(key);
  let fullDate = temp.getFullYear()+'-'+temp.getMonth()+'-'+temp.getDate();
  if(op[fullDate]){
    for(let val in data['metrics'][key])
    {
      if(op[fullDate][val])
       op[fullDate][val] += data['metrics'][key][val]
      else op[fullDate][val] = data['metrics'][key][val]
    }
  } else {
    op[fullDate] = {...data['metrics'][key]};
  }

}

console.log(op);
```

Comment: OH MY GOD you are a Prince Among Men! Thank you I'm going to post this as the answer. Works perfectly. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: @CHays412 always happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the dates' [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), get the date by splitting the string, and add an object if doesn't exist. Iterate the values' entries with [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), add the values to the date object:

```js
const data = {"metrics":{"2018-12-26 18:00:00":{"20":451,"30":48},"2018-12-26 19:00:00":{"20":165},"2018-12-27 00:00:00":{"20":177,"30":8},"2018-12-27 01:00:00":{"20":220},"2018-12-27 02:00:00":{"20":220},"2018-12-27 03:00:00":{"20":177,"30":8},"2018-12-27 04:00:00":{"20":220},"2018-12-28 00:00:00":{"20":93},"2018-12-28 01:00:00":{"20":76},"2018-12-28 02:00:00":{"20":76},"2018-12-28 03:00:00":{"20":57},"2018-12-28 04:00:00":{"20":76},"2018-12-28 15:00:00":{"20":130,"30":10}}};

const result = Object.entries(data.metrics)
  .reduce((r, [date, values]) => {
    const [d] = date.split(/\s+/);
    const current = r[d] ? r[d] : (r[d] = {});
    
    for(const [k, v] of Object.entries(values)) {
      current[k] = (current[k] || 0) + v;
    }
    
    return r;
  }, {});
  
console.log(result);
```